# SaaS application automatically generate virtual host

Tags: apache, shell, virtualhost, saas, vhosts

I am building a SaaS application which allows users to use their own domain names.

After the user registers, I need to create a new apache SSL virtual host file for that new subscriber.

What is the most secure way to do this?

I thought about using a shell script that I can trigger after the registration process completes and that will generate the new host file.
However, such scripts need to be run as root and I don't feel like giving the http user root privileges.

Comment: Define "the most secure way" please. And context. And why you believe you need a host file entry: A host file would be used on the current machine, but nowhere on the internet. Why would you use this to resolve a domain name?

Comment: @OlafKock I need a host file so I can add an ssl certificate for each domain name ... And by most secure I mean the most likely to not cause manipulation or generation of fake hosts by an attacker for example

Comment: I've never heard of a requirement for a hosts file entry in order to generate a tls certificate...

Comment: @OlafKock Fair enough ... Then how would you specify an SSLCertificateFile for a domain name hosted on the server without creating a vhost?

Comment: Ha - I probably misread the short "host file" as referring to `/etc/hosts`, something that somebody else recently asked as well. Sorry about that. VirtualHost: Yes, you need that, one way or another. But: You don't need to be root to write that file, and you could script a "reload your configuration" outside of that process, e.g. in cron

Comment: @AmeerElsherif did you make any progress with this issue? I do have saas app and I need to generate ssl certificates for each user based on thier domain name.

Comment: @MoauyaMeghari Actually no, I didn't properly solve it yet ... In my application I have 2 options for the customer to choose from which are either domain or subdomain on my main domain ... Most of my customers are currently using the subdomain options so a wildcard SSL certificate was enough for me ... And I am currently handling the others manually as it is not high piority for me in the mean time ... I will kepp you updated when that changes

Comment: @AmeerElsherif Thanks, I think of excuting a shell script to create a virtual host for the domain and generate a ssl using certbot. I didn't do it yet but I'll give it a try.